# statsmodels and linearmodels produce different results for a fixed effects regression

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

I did statsmodels sm.ols regression with added fixed effects as dummies. Then I considered if it was better to use random effects and remembered that Hausman test could provide indication which model is more appropriate to use. To run that test I had to create both RE and FE models. After making RE model using linearmodels package, I noticed that both models should be done in the same package to make this test. I then remade the initial fixed effects regression and noticed that it gives very similar coefficients for the IVs but completely different R squared scores (0.89 using statsmodels vs 0.29 using linearmodels) and the linearmodels output is also missing all of the fixed effect dummies.

```
# statsmodels regression
import statsmodels.api as sm
X = dfd[['interest', 'unemp', 'inflation', 'shock', 'ESG']]
X = sm.add_constant(X)
FE = pd.get_dummies(dfd[['compname']], drop_first=True)
X_fe = pd.concat([X, FE], axis=1)
X_fe = X_fe.astype(float)
y_fe = list(dfd['price'])
model_fe = sm.OLS(y_fe, X_fe).fit()
print(model_fe.summary())


# linearmodels regression
from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS
dfd1 = dfd.copy() 
dfd1 = dfd1.set_index(['compname', 'time'])
y_fe = dfd1['price']
X_fe = dfd1[['interest', 'unemp', 'inflation', 'shock', 'ESG']]
X_fe = sm.add_constant(X_fe)
model_fe = PanelOLS(y_fe, X_fe, entity_effects=True).fit()
print(model_fe)
```

So now I am basically out of ideas which one I did correctly and why R squared are differing so much. I looked around the internet for clues and discovered that the packages are handling fixed effects somehow differently but I just cannot understand that the difference in results could be so extreme.

Comment: did you check all rsquared versions in linearmodels ? https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/panel/panel/linearmodels.panel.results.PanelEffectsResults.html#linearmodels.panel.results.PanelEffectsResults